# WSO2 API Manager does not display resources list when started as a service. JSPException while including path '/resources/resource.jsp'

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After I have installed wso2am-1.10.0 and have started it as a service with YAJSW (as recommended in the installation docs), the Browse Resources page in the carbon interface throws a JSP Exception. Any ideas why? (It works correctly if I start wso2am manually from the command line.)

WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0; YAJSW 11.11; running on Windows Server 2012

```
[2016-01-28 15:36:59,578] ERROR - JspTilesRequestContext JSPException while including path '/resources/resource.jsp'. 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /resources/resource.jsp at line 229

 <% if (relationsFound) {
 String relationsPath = "../relations/relations.jsp?path=" + RegistryUtil.getPath(request).replaceAll("&","%26");
 %>
 <jsp:include page="<%=relationsPath%>"/>
 <% } %>

 <% if (retentionFound && !resourceTreeEntryBean.getCollection()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the scenario using the steps given on [1] and the additional steps given on[2] and I was able to successfully install the service and run. Could you please verify your steps with the below steps

The approach I followed was :

1.Create a folder called apim_home and copy the downloaded WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 and set the carbon_home under environment variables

2.Install jdk7 and set the java_home under environment variables

3.add the below lines to the wrapper.conf within   C:\apim_home\wso2am-1.10.0\bin\yajsw and then copy the wrapper.conf into C:\apim_home\yajsw-stable-11.11\conf of YAJSW 11.11

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dwso2.carbon.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\carbon.xml
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dwso2.registry.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\registry.xml
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\user-mgt.xml
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dwso2.transports.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\mgt-transports.xml
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

4.Access the path C:\apim_home\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat and run installService.bat. Once we navigate into Administrative Services and click on Services a service by the name "WSO2 Carbon" should exist

5.Next, run the command startService.bat and once we navigate into Administrative Services and click on Services a service by the name "WSO2 Carbon" should be in status "Running"

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

[2]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15423